# Delete by id and parent_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
rule_id    parent_id
1          0
2          0
3          2
4          2
5          3
```

When I use a DELETE query and delete let's say **id 2**, I want to erase the rows that have **parent_id** as that id.

After deleting successfully, the table should look like:

```
rule_id    parent_id
1          0
5          3
```

So everything that had **2** is now gone.

I've tried this and I was certain that it would work, but it did not.

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . RULES_TABLE .   
    ' WHERE rule_id = ' . (int) $rule_id . 
        (($type == 'cat') ? ' AND parent_id = ' . (int) $rule_id : '');
```

Comment: What's rule_id? That's not mentioned in your table description

Comment: Then I don't think you need it? Surely all you need is `'DELETE FROM table WHERE parent_id='. (int)$ruleid`

Comment: I do need it. What if rule_id is not the parent of any rows, but I still want to delete that rule id?

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that from the question - see pilotcam's answer, in that case.

Comment: Surely the best way to do this would be to have the relationship defined foreign key and `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: I guess what you want is chain effect, when you delete say row with rule_id=2, it will remove rows with rule_id=3 and 4. Removing these rows will further remove rows having parent_id = 3, leaving only row with rule_id = 1; If so then you should use foreign key constraint. If not, then look for other solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an 'OR' in your where clause.

```
DELETE FROM RULES_TABLE WHERE rule_id=? OR parent_id=?
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be silly but why don't you just use the old good referential integrity from INNODB?

Setting a reflexive foreign reference key `(rule_id, parent_id)` with `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause would solve the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

Change your "AND" to "OR":

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . RULES_TABLE .   
' WHERE rule_id = ' . (int) $rule_id . 
    (($type == 'cat') ? ' OR parent_id = ' . (int) $rule_id : '');
```